# How to store photos only in SD card

Tags: sd-card, photos

I store some photos on albums that is stored in SD card, however when I take new photos the photos are stored on a new album that has both SD card and camera symbols. I guess it is stored on both device and SD card. How can I ensure that newly taken photos are stored only on the SD card on an album without the camera symbol?

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is erroneous. Camera symbol means that it's an album of pictures made with phone camera (and not screenshots or downloaded pictures or pictures of some other app). SD-Card symbol means the pictures are stored on the sd-card.

You can always see where a picture is stored in picture details/properties.